# ClassNotFound Exception when configuring RestEasy

Tags: rest, jboss, resteasy

I'm having trouble while configuring RestEasy with Jboss 5.1GA. I have done everything that the installation manual says to do, Basically downloaded the restEasy zip, copied all the jars inside the lib folder to my war and configured the web.xml like this:

```
<listener>
<listener-class>
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
</servlet-class>
<init-param>

<param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
<param-value>com.base.BaseApplication</param-value>
</init-param>
```

My Application class looks like this:

```
public class BaseApplication {
private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet();
 private Set<Class<?>> empty = new HashSet();

 public BaseApplication() {

 // ADD YOUR RESTFUL RESOURCES HERE
     singletons.add(new QuoteResource());
 }

 public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
 {
 return this.empty;
 }

 public Set<Object> getSingletons()
 {
 return this.singletons;
 }
}
```

The same configuration works fine on JBoss 4.2.3GA, but when deploying to JBoss 5.1 I got the following exception. I can't figure out why RestEasy it's trying to instanciate a CDI class not available with Jboss 5.1.0.

```
14:50:41,547 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to PreReal: name=vfszip:/C:/Java/servers/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/club-demo/deploy/club-demo-internet.war/ state=PostClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PreReal
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfszip:/C:/Java/servers/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/club-demo/deploy/club-demo-internet.war/
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:177)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
**Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/inject/spi/AnnotatedType**
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:63)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:572)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:532)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:530)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:507)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:134)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:131)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:452)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:251)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:150)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:265)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1119)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:798)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:441)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.visitor.AbstractResourceContext.loadClass(AbstractResourceContext.java:118)
at org.jboss.webbeans.integration.deployer.env.WebBeanDiscoveryDeployer$WBDiscoveryVisitor.visit(WebBeanDiscoveryDeployer.java:134)
at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:264)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.vfs.helpers.WrappingVirtualFileHandlerVisitor.visit(WrappingVirtualFileHandlerVisitor.java:62)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVFSContext.visit(AbstractVFSContext.java:361)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVFSContext.visit(AbstractVFSContext.java:376)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVFSContext.visit(AbstractVFSContext.java:376)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVFSContext.visit(AbstractVFSContext.java:376)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVFSContext.visit(AbstractVFSContext.java:306)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVFSContext.visit(AbstractVFSContext.java:374)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVFSContext.visit(AbstractVFSContext.java:306)
at org.jboss.virtual.VFS.visit(VFS.java:421)
at org.jboss.virtual.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:437)
at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:101)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.classloader.VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.visit(VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.java:160)
at org.jboss.webbeans.integration.deployer.env.WebBeanDiscoveryDeployer.deploy(WebBeanDiscoveryDeployer.java:109)
at org.jboss.webbeans.integration.deployer.env.WebBeanDiscoveryDeployer.deploy(WebBeanDiscoveryDeployer.java:45)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractOptionalVFSRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractOptionalVFSRealDeployer.java:57)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractOptionalRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractOptionalRealDeployer.java:74)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
... 29 more
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.AnnotatedType**
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:292)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1119)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:798)
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:441)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
... 69 more
```

Please suggest what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, just deleted the resteasy-cdi-2.1.0.GA.jar and the problem disappeared, I just hope this jar won't cause me problems in the future.

Comment: You have to wait at least 2 days before you can accept your own answer on your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug. You have to include javax.inject in your maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The test scope is optional.

See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-157 for more information.