# JBoss6 with RestEasy client

Tags: java, resteasy, jboss6.x

I want to consume a REST service in my web app (.war with 6.0.0.Final), and recently switched from jersey to resteasy (because of [JBoss6 with REST client (jersey-client)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593560)).

My client code is this simple example (perfectly working when called from the console):

```
ResteasyProviderFactory providerFactory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
RegisterBuiltin.register(providerFactory);

ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(restUrl);
request.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

ClientResponse<MyJaxbClass> response = request.get(MyJaxbClass.class);
```

At the beginning I hoped that everything for RESTeasy is available in JBoss, but while accessing the method I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.createDefaultExecutorInstance(ClientRequest.java:115)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.getDefaultExecutor(ClientRequest.java:94)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.<init>(ClientRequest.java:125)
  at my.own.MyRestEasyClient.members(MyRestEasyClient.java:42)
```

Well, not a big deal! Although I'm wondering why the deprecated `commons-httpcomponents` is used, I added `commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1` to my .war. But the error did not disappeared. I double-checked that `commons-httpclient-3.1.jar` is in the war. Then I removed commons-httpcomponents`and added`org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:2.1.0.GA`and`org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:2.1.0.GA`. To avoid (maybe I'm already in) jar-hell I used the resteasy-version which is bundled with JBoss6, but now I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationTypeMismatchException: Incorrectly
  typed data found for annotation element public abstract
  javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm
  org.jboss.xb.annotations.JBossXmlSchema.elementFormDefault()
  (Found data of type Ljavax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlNsForm;.QUALIFIED)
```

This is not really specifict but I got similar errors if I bundle jars into my .war which are already available in JBoss. I've found [ClassNotFound Exception when configuring RestEasy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169171), but this seems not to be related to my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had the same problem a few days ago, but found this bug report that helped us
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8841

To fix (As mentioned in the bug report):

> I added commons-httpclient-3.1.jar in deployers/resteasy.deployer to
>   correct the exception. Adding the jar to my webapp didn't worked

And this worked for us.